# Creating a windows shortcut (.lnk) to TortoiseHG's Repository Explorer

Tags: command-line, tortoisehg

Is it possible to create a shortcut (a link, an icon on the Desktop) to one of my repositorie's Repository Explorer(TortoiseHG)? I don't like to navigate all the time to the folder and right click -> repository Explorer, i'm looking for a faster method, using a shortcut that can be accessed from anywhere.

Comment: I'm currently using version 1.1.7 of TortoiseHG, boundled with Kiln, and I'm not sure if the >2 version is compatible with Kiln

Comment: I am using 2.0.3 with kiln and haven't experienced any problems.  The 2.0 interface is definitely worth the upgrade.

Comment: After a few tests, I have issues with Kiln and TortoiseHG 2. I get an error message when updating. They say it's related to KbFiles extension https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/182/error-__init__-takes-exactly-5-arguments-4

Comment: Sorry to hear you are having problems.  I don't have the kiln client tools (and extensions) installed so haven't hit any issues with the KbFiles extension, as I don't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for 1.X, one option is to create a shortcut using the `-R` switch to specify the repository directory:

```
hgtk.exe -R <repopath> log
```

Another option is put a shortcut to your repository directory on your desktop, then right-click it and select "Hg Repository Explorer".

Answer (score 4):

The latest version of TortoiseHg (>2.0) includes the 'Workbench' which you can create a shortcut to.  In the workbench you can register all of your repositories for easy access.

Answer (score 3):

With TortoiseHg v2.x, there are 2 easy ways to make a shortcut like this.

#### The first way, is to modify a windows shortcut to the thgw.exe file.

1. Find thgw.exe and make a shortcut to it. (Probably in C:\Program File\TortoiseHg)
2. Right-click the shortcut and choose "Properties".
3. In the input field labeled "Target", add the following text after what's there:

   (don't forget to fill in the correct path to your project)

   ```
   -R "C:\Path\To\Project"
   ```
4. Hit "OK" and launch the shortcut.

#### The second way, is to create a batch file to launch the Workbench.

1. Create a new text file (in notepad) and paste the following script:

   ```
   :: Point this to the directory that TortoiseHG is intalled to.
   set APP_DIR="C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg"

   :: Point this to the directory of your project.
   set REPO_DIR="C:\Path\To\Project"

   :: This launches the Workbench at your project's directory.
   call %APP_DIR%\thgw.exe -R %REPO_DIR%
   ```
2. Update the 2 directory variables in the script. Save & Close.
3. Rename the file to use a .bat extension: `MyProject.bat`
4. Launch it.